# Why is the Scaffold content in my Flutter app not going under my custom AppBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar, preferredsize

When I use a regular `AppBar` in a `Scaffold`, all of the content is pushed down so it's not covered. However, now that I created a custom `FloatingAppBar`, the content goes under the app bar even though I'm using it the same way. Also, since the `FloatingAppBar` has to implement `PreferredSizeWidget`, I also have to give it a preferred size from the height which makes the height of the app bar very small when I use it in a bottom modal widget. Is there any way to get around that? Here is a screenshot of the issue and the code for the custom app bar:

[image: Floating app bar covers content]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FloatingAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const FloatingAppBar(
      {Key? key,
      required this.title,
      required this.leading,
      required this.actions})
      : super(key: key);

  final Widget leading;
  final Widget title;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
        child: Container(
          color: const Color(0xFFd3d8e9),
          height: 120,
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  leading,
                  title,
                  Row(
                    children: actions,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(120);
}
```

Comment: Can you include where and how you are using this widget

Comment: I just realized that in the scaffold I enabled `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` because I want the background color to go behind the app bar too. So removing this fixes the covering issue but then how can I have the background color behind it?

Comment: Do you mean color on AppBar? Sorry not getting it, If it possible you can inclue two image of two different state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this issue is that you set the appbar height 120, but the actual height you give to appbar is 120 + padding top + padding bottom. in order to fix it , you could do this:

```
Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(120 + 40 + 40);
```

For your color issue, because you know the app bar height 120 in this case, you can add top padding to your scaffold body to fix the background color issue.

Comment: I update my answer for background color behind the appbar issue